# The parameters of the Main function in C++

Tags: c++

When I try to compile this code, an error appears :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char* p = "Hello";
    return 0;
}
```

> error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [6]' to 'char *'

This error is fixed when I add the word `const` in the declaration of `p`.

This code compiles and runs:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char* p = "Hello";
    return 0;
}
```

So my question is : How is the `main()` function able to take `char *argv[]` (as a parameter) and not `const char *argv[]` (as a parameter)?

`int main (int argc, char *argv[])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see what is happening in your example on case by case basis:

##### Case 1

Here we consider the statement:

```
char* p = "Hello";
```

On the right hand side of the above statement, we've the **string literal** `"Hello"` which is of type `const char[6]`. There are two ways to understand why the above statement didn't work.

1. In some contexts, `const char[6]` **decays** to a `const char*` due to **type decay**. This basically means that on the right hand side we will have a `const char*` while on the left hand side we have a `char*`. Note also that this means that on the right hand side we've a **low-level const** but on the left hand side we don't have any low-level const. So, the given statement won't work. For the statement to work we've to make sure that the left hand side should've either same or greater low-level const qualifier than the right hand side.

A few example would illustrate the point:

```
int arr1[] = {1,2,3};
int* ptr1 = arr1; //this works because arr1 decays to int* and both sides have no low level const

const int arr2[] = {1,2,3};
int* ptr2 = arr2; //won't work, right hand side will have a low level const(as arr2 decays to const char*) while the left hand side will not have a low level const

const int* ptr3 = arr2; //this works, both side will have a low level const
```

2. The second way(which is basically equivalent to the 1st) to understand this is that since `"Hello"` is of type `const char[6]`, so if we are allowed to write `char* p = "Hello";` then that would mean that we're allowed to change the elements of the array. But note that the type `const char[6]` means that the `char` elements inside the array are immutable(or non-changable). Thus, allowing `char* p = "Hello";` would allow changing `const` marked data, which should not happen(since the data was not supposed to change as it was marked `const`).  So to prevent this from happening we have to use `const char* p = "Hello";` so that the pointer `p` is not allowed to change the `const` marked data.

---

##### Case 2

Here we consider the declaration:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

In the above declaration, the type of the second parameter named `argv` is actually a `char**`. That is, `argv` is a *pointer to a pointer to a `char`*. This is because a `char* []` **decays** to a **`char**`** due to **type decay**. For example, the below given declarations are equivalent:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]); //first declaration
int main (int argc, char **argv);  //RE-DECLARATION. Equivalent to the above declaration
```

In other words, `argv` is a pointer that points to the first element of an array with elements of type `char*`. Moreover, each elements `argv[i]` of the array(with elements of type `char*`) itself point to a character which is the start of a *null terminated* character string. That is, each element `argv[i]` points to the first element of an array with elements of type `char`(and not `const char`). Thus, there is no need for `const char*`. A diagram is given for illustration purposes:

[image: argc and argv]

Comment: when you said ( due to type decay ) in case 1 and case 2 .
 did you mean ( Array-to-pointer decay ) ????? @Anoop Rana

Comment: @f877576 Yes, in your example it is *array to pointer decay*. I used the more general term *type decay* that also includes some other categories of decay like *function to pointer decay*.

Comment: ( Yes, in your example it is array to pointer decay )
( in your example ) means in my 2 cases ( the 2 cases in my question ) not just the first case , right ?? @Anoop Rana

Comment: @f877576 Yes, in both of your examples there will be array to pointer decay just as in my example containing `int` arrays.

Comment: the last question :) 

(  just as in my example containing int arrays ) this is your example ( the example you mean ) 

`int arr1[] = {1,2,3};`
`int* ptr1 = arr1; //this works because arr1 decays to int* and both sides have no low level const`

`const int arr2[] = {1,2,3};`
`int* ptr2 = arr2; //won't work, right hand side will have a low level const(as arr2 decays to const char*) while the left hand side will not have a low level const`

`const int* ptr3 = arr2; //this works, both side will have a low level const`
@Anoop Rana

Comment: @f877576 Yes, and as i explained in the comments of my example the array to pointer decay happens there(in my example) too.

Answer (score 4):

`"Hello"` is a string literal, which has a type of `const char[6]`. You can't set a non-const `char*` pointer to point at a `const char[]`, hence the error.  Doing so would grant the caller access to mutate read-only data.

The `char*` pointers in the `argv[]` parameter of `main()` are pointing at `char[]` arrays which are allocated and filled dynamically at runtime, when the program's startup code parses the calling process's command line parameters before calling `main()`. They are not pointing at string literals, and thus do not need to be `const char*`.

Comment: do you mean what happen is exactly this : ` char o[5]; ` ` char* p;` ` p= o;` ?????????? ( in the case of the parameter of  main ( ) ) @Remy Lebeau

Comment: @f877576 sort of, but that is not what the startup code actually does. It is more *equivalent* (not exactly) to something like this instead: `char **argv = new char*[numParams+1]; for (int i = 0; i < numParams; ++i) { argv[i] = new char[strlen(params[i])+1); strcpy(argv[i], params[i]); } argv[numParams] = NULL; main(numParams, argv); for (int i = 0; i < numParams; ++i) { delete[] argv[i]; } delete[] argv;`

Comment: @f877576 `char* []` means an *array of pointers to `char`*. Thus, `argv` is a *pointer to a pointer to a `char`* i.e., a `char**`.

Comment: An array and a pointer are not exactly the same, but similar and in the C language an array is often automatically *decayed* into a pointer to the first element and an offset to a pointer can be accessed with brackets []. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay For C++ there also is the explicit `std::decay`

Comment: I am sorry for bothering you . argv is a pointer to a pointer to a char which is nothing but char** ( is ( is nothing but ) mean ( is ) ) So the sentence will be argv is a pointer to a pointer to a char which is char**  ????
@Anoop Rana

Comment: Yes, why the '????'? char is char. char* is pointer to a char. char** is pointer to pointer to char. char*** is pointer to pointer to pointer to char.

Comment: I am not good in english so I my question is : is ( nothing but ) means ( is ) @Sebastian

Comment: @f877576 Yes basically, saying *"`argv` is nothing but a `char**`"* is equivalent to saying *"`argv` is a `char**`"*. See my edited comment above.

Comment: Yes. It means 'is'. More exact synonyms would be 'simply is' or 'just is' or 'only is' or 'there remains nothing except'. But only you yourself used the term 'is nothing but'.

Comment: When you said " hense the error " Did you mean " hence the error " ? @Remy Lebeau

Comment: @f877576 Yes, they meant "hence" instead of "hense". It was a typo which has been corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: You can actually mutate `argv`, string literals are immutable in c++.
eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char** argv) {
  char* p = new char[3];
  p[0] = 'H'; p[1] = 'i'; p[2] = 0;
  argv[0][0] = ':';
  argv[0][1] = 'P';
  argv[0][2] = '\n';
  std::cout << p << argv[0];
  delete[] p;
}
```

[Same code on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/deaxd43vr)

This is, as far as I know, valid c++, with well-defined behavior.
`char* x = "An immutable char const[].";` is not.
You can probably cast const away with `const_cast`.
But any attempt to modify the string pointed to by `x` would cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Is the cast undefined or actually writing to the char array?

Comment: do you mean`char* x = "An immutable char const[].";` is not valid c++ ( is not an defined behavior ) ???? AND do you mean even when I use `const_cast` with string literals if I try to modify the string this would cause an undefined behavior ???? ( I mean is  this what you meant in your answer ? )  @viraltaco_

Comment: There is no (valid) conversion between the type of the literal `char const[]` and `char*` in C++ (such a conversion would discard the cv-qualifier [of the element pointed to]). If you use `const_cast` to cast away const in order to mutate a const variable: it's undefined behavior. [dcl.type](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type#cv-4).
If you need a mutable string please use `std::string`. 

So, yes: `char* x = "An immutable char const[].";` is not valid c++.  
However, `char x[] = "This is fine!";` is "fine", it's just an array. Please use `std::string`, though.