# Is it valid to use const char*[] as the type of second parameter of main

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, program-entry-point

I am learning C++ and [learnt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71965951/18843922) that the following given declarations are equivalent:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]); //first declaration
int main (int argc, char **argv);  //RE-DECLARATION. Equivalent to the above declaration
```

My question is that if i change the declaration to say:

```
//note the added const
int main (int argc,const char *argv[]); //IS THIS VALID?
```

Is the above declaration where i have added a const valid? That is, does the C++ standard allow this modified declaration with the added const.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `const` changes the type of the function. It is not declaration of the same function.

Whether that is valid for `main` in particular, depends on language implementation:

> [basic.start.main]
>
> An implementation shall not predefine the main function.
> Its type shall have C++ language linkage and it shall have a declared return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined.
> An implementation shall allow both
>
> - a function of () returning int and
> - a function of (int, pointer to pointer to char) returning int
>
> as the type of main ([dcl.fct]).

It may in theory be valid in some implementation, but it will not be portable to all systems.

Comment: @Richard The rule says that the type is implementation-defined. If the implementation-defined type matches that declaration, then it is allowed. It it doesn't match, then it isn't allowed. It is not guaranteed to be allowed because it is neither of the two mandated alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

According to cppreference.com ([main_function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function)), `main` should have one of the following forms:

```
int main () { body }    (1)     
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { body }  (2)     
/* another implementation-defined form, with int as return type */  (3)
```

Using `int main (int argc,const char *argv[])` (your suggested variation) works for example in MSVC. This case falls under form (3) above.

But since it is `implementation-defined` it is better to avoid (even if works in your current environment).